# filtered content of corpus by custom function with R

Tags: r, tm, corpus

I want to analysis filtered texts by custom function (function with parameters) using R.

I used readlines function to extract my text and I get large list with 258 lists. Then, using VCorpus(VectorSource(files)) I get my corpus with original text, create corpus from vector. I bug here, I want to find way to get corpus filtered or to filter my files before inserting into corpus.

My aim is to deal with the corpus for the rest of my analysis.

This code allow me to analysis the original text, how can I filter the content of my corpus :

```
filenames <- list.files(getwd(),pattern="*.txt") 
files <- lapply(filenames,readLines,warn=FALSE) 
docs <- VCorpus(VectorSource(files))
```

Comment: What do you want to filter the corpus for? What's your goal at the end of this project? (That could change how you do the steps leading to it.) It looks like you're fairly new to SO; welcome to the community! Whenever you ask questions, If you want great answers quickly, it's best to make your question reproducible. This includes sample data, any libraries you are using, and the outcome you're looking for. Check it out: [making R reproducible questions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269).

Comment: Thank you very much, I managed to solve my problem on this question I will know for the next times!